# Operator defined in which package ? Warning: Error in %||%: could not find function "%||%"

Tags: r, operator-overloading

How can I find the R package where this new operator %||% is defined?

Comment: Any package could define an implementation for that operator so it kind of depends on what you expect that operator to do. Perhaps the most common versions come from `purrr` or `rlang`.

Comment: Using `getAnywhere("%||%")` will tell you .

Comment: getAnywhere will not tell you anything unless the package with that function is already loaded. As always the help page should be consulted: ``They do not search literally “anywhere”: for example, local evaluation frames and namespaces that are not loaded will not be searched``